# Difference between LENGTH[...] and fn:length(...) in JSP EL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

What is the difference between the `LENGTH[...]` and the JSTL function `fn:length(...)`?

I tried to search to difference but I did not see any example that uses the first one.

Here is an example:

```
<c:when test="${object.field ne null || LENGTH[object.field] > 0}"> 
    <td valign="top">
        .....print something
    </td>
</c:when>
```

Comment: Maybe because the first one doesn't exist? Where did you read/hear/see about the first one? Isn't it just a misinterpretation of your side? The brace notation `[]` is often used to access properties by dynamic keys.

Comment: actually, at my work they asked me to change every instance of LENGTH[..] to use jstl length function. and the code is in production, so I know it was working...
I was not able to find the LENGTH[] by googling because google always ignores the [] and ends up returning the regular fn:length function

Comment: Copypaste some code examples where this is been used.

Comment: I assume that the one extra `}` is just a typo? It's namely syntactically wrong.

Comment: yes, Actually a typo from my end, everything else is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since there is no such function like `LENGTH[...]` in standard JSP/JSTL/EL, it's impossible to tell about the differences. The [`fn:length()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/length.fn.html) is the only way to obtain the length of a `String`, an `Object[]` or `Collection`.

```
${fn:length(someCollection)}
```

---

**Update** as per your (fixed) example:

```
<c:when test="${object.field ne null || LENGTH[object.field] > 0}">
```

I've never seen this before. It look like that your webapp/servletcontainer is using a custom EL resolver. If this is true, you should see it been declared in webapp's `web.xml` file.

Regardless, you'd rather like to use the EL `empty` keyword here. It not only checks for `null`, but also for the length of the `String`, `Object[]` or `Collection`.

```
<c:when test="${not empty object.field}">
```

No need for `fn:length()` here.

---

The brace notation `[]` is in turn by the way often used to access properties by dynamic keys. E.g.

```
${bean[propertyname]}
```

If `propertyname` resolves to "foo", then the above does effectively the same as `${bean.foo}`. It's also often used on `Map` objects in the scope.

Comment: Since you are confident about the answer, I will assume that the code that had the LENGTH[] was never executed (i.e surrounding if was never true) that is why it was not breaking anything. Thanks a lot for the quick response.

Comment: I would however include some examples in the question. It could be as good a misinterpretation from your side. Maybe they just meant to replace the scriptlet `<%= array.length %>` by EL `${fn:length(array)}`.

Comment: I totally agree with BalusC. I have never come across or seen anyone using LENGTH function.